# sentence in one line using awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have extracted data by commands and save it in kwrite file but now I want to retrieve some important data from it but the data  should be ideally in 1 line while in my case it breaks  in to 2,3 lines.The lines start with Jpak is of interest. 
Data:

```
Jpak= its just a sample data for posting,
solve the query asap

Breadth=44


***** less*****
--
Effective search space used: 2418848120


Jpak= To work late into the night, alluding to the
 time before electric lighting

Breadth=75


***** less*****
--


Jpak= Speak of an issue, (mostly current) which ,
many people ,
are talking 

Breadth=22


***** less *****
- -
```

Desired Output:

```
Jpak= its just a sample data for posting solve the query asap

Jpak= To work late into the night alluding to the time before electric lighting

Jpak= Speak of an issue (mostly current) which many people  are talking
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format sample input and output. And what have you tried?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Should we only look for lines starting with `Jpak=` or could that change? Do you want to remove all commas? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: yes only the lines starting with Jpak

Answer (score 1):

### Pure `sed` solution

Sorry I'm not familiar (enough) with `awk`, but this does the job:

```
sed '/Jpak=/,/^$/!d' sample|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/,/ /g;s/ \{2,\}/ /g;s/Jpak/\n\nJpak/g'
```

<sub>Gathered together from [sed1line](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) and [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed).</sub>

#### Output

```
Jpak= its just a sample data for posting solve the query asap

Jpak= To work late into the night alluding to the time before electric lighting

Jpak= Speak of an issue (mostly current) which many people are talking
```

Using this chain of commands the output begins with two empty lines (not shown here), add `|sed '1,2d'` to the end of the chain to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n00E '/Jpak=/ and s/\s+/ /g and say' ex.txt
```

- `-n00E` -- for each empty-line separated paragraph do...
- `/Jpak=/ and` -- find the desired pattern and...
- `s/\s+/ /g` -- substitute sequences of spaces, newline and tabs, by a single space
- `and say` -- and say what was found.

Output is:

```
Jpak= its just a sample data for posting, solve the query asap 
Jpak= To work late into the night, alluding to the time before electric lighting 
Jpak= Speak of an issue, (mostly current) which , many people , are talking
```